# Delete a corrupt file in debain

Tags: debian, permissions, software-installation

How to delete this file?

[image: Root Folder]

I installed "Network Configuration Management" from ManageEngine:
[Network Configuration Management](http://www.manageengine.com/network-configuration-manager/?)

AllPrd

I tried to run that .exe ("MSIHandler.exe") file (my fault) and
got this corrupted file.

2 things:

1. How to delete that file?
2. How to run the installed Network Configuration Management?

Comment: Tried using terminal, but cant access the filename, its so obscure, thus rm command fails. Looking for a root file manager.

Comment: You're showing us a screenshot of PCMan, a file manager, and asking how to delete one of the files displayed in its view of a folder; and when you explain what you have tried you _don't_ say that you have tried simply using the file manager to delete the file, let alone what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
ls -b /opt/ManageEngine/OpManager
```

to get a directory listing where the non-printable characters have been replaced with escape sequences (`\NNN` and similar) that can be copy-pasted to the command line as-is.

Another similar option is

```
ls -q /opt/ManageEngine/OpManager
```

which replaces unprintable characters with question marks. Since a question mark is a shell wildcard meaning "any single character here", this type of output is also readily useable as a parameter for the `rm` command. However, it is possible that more than one file would match the wildcard string, so I'd recommend using `sudo rm -i /opt/ManageEngine/OpManager/<copy-pasted wildcard string here>`, so you can confirm that you're deleting just the right file and nothing else.

The old-school way would be to use

```
ls -i /opt/ManageEngine/OpManager
```

to see a directory listing with each file's inode number listed with it, and then delete the problem file using the inode number. First confirm that you're getting the right file:

```
sudo find /opt/ManageEngine/OpManager -inum <inode number here> -type f -print
```

Then delete it:

```
sudo find /opt/ManageEngine/OpManager -inum <inode number here> -type f -delete
```

Comment: Thanks @telcoM, but I resolved it by simply removing the parent directory. Now what about the second question: "How to run the installed Network Configuration Management?"

Comment: [The documentation for Network Configuration Manager](https://www.manageengine.com/network-configuration-manager/help/installation-getting-started.html) says there should be a `bin` sub-directory in wherever you've installed the software, and in there should be a `run.sh` script.